# Load existing Model in Weka Knowledge Flow

Tags: weka

I am trying to plot multiple ROC curves in the same diagram in Weka. I have learnt that I can do this in Weka Knowledge Flow using "Model Performance Chart". However, I can't figure out how to do this for existing models.

I have tried using ArffLoader and TestSetMaker to generate the testing data, and connected this to a suitable Classifier icon (eg AdaBoostM1 when this is the kind of model I am trying to load). In the configurations of the Classifier icon I choose "load model" and in the Status bar it says "Loaded model.". However, when I run this it says "ERROR: no trained/loaded classifier to use for prediction".

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a post that was published [here](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?90668-using-separate-training-and-test-files) that indicates some ambiguity in the meaning of the error.  It also continues to state that the order of attributes and the number and order of values is also rather important.

It also states that '*for performance results to be computed, your Knowledge Flow process will need a "ClassifierPerformanceEvaluator" component after the classifier and before a TextViewer component.*'

If you are new with the KnowledgeFlow environment, there is a great tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yCceL6YCMn4) from Rushdi Shams that details the general process.

Below is a sample workflow that has generated desirable results using AdaBoost (preloaded model):

[image: KnowledgeFlow Diagram using AdaBoost]

Hope this Helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have found that same post, and I have already checked for all those things and none of them seem to be the problem. I have a ClassifierPerformanceEvaluator in my process flow, when I train a new model instead of loading an existing one it works just fine. Also I made sure the model was trained on a compatible data set to the test set, so thats not it either.

Comment: I was able to try the KnowledgeFlow environment successfully on a previously trained AdaBoost model and estimates came through successfully to the TextViewer.  Sorry that it isn't working for you.

Comment: Can you tell me how you set up your Knowledge flow / show a screenshot? I feel like I must be missing something basic here. Thanks again, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @MatthewSpencer I have also tried with Weka knowledge flow but I did not get start loading option from ArffLoader. What kind of error is this?